# How to fix the error "there are more elements are supplied than there are to replace" in a for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

Can someone help me with this? I got the cut_interval code to work for a single test column, but can't seem to get it to work in a for loop to have it run on all of the columns.

```
#Bin worker data into three groups (low/medium/high %methylation) for the cpg cg10757709
#This code works
cg10757709_interval <- cut_interval(cpgs$cg10757709, n=3, labels = c("low","med","high"))
View(cg10757709_interval)

#Write a loop so that data for each of the significant cpgs will be binned into low, medium, and high groups
#This code gives an error (that there are more elements are supplied than there are to replace)
cpgs_interval <- matrix(ncol = length(cpgs), nrow = 29) 
for (i in seq_along(cpgs)) {
  cpgs_interval[[i]] <- cut_interval(cpgs[[i]], n=3, labels = c("low","med","high"))
}
View(cpgs_interval)
```

The error says "Error in cpgs_interval[[i]] <- cut_interval(cpgs[[i]], n = 3, labels = c("low",  : more elements supplied than there are to replace". Should I not be using a matrix for cpgs_interval? Or is something else the problem? I'm rather new to writing for loops. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `cpgs_interval` is a matrix.  If you want to put the variable into the ith column of the matrix, you could do:

```
for (i in seq_along(cpgs)) {
  cpgs_interval[,i] <- cut_interval(cpgs[[i]], n=3, labels = c("low","med","high"))
}
```

That said, you might be better off making `cpgs_interval` a data frame, then you'll retain the factor rather than turning it into text.

Comment: Thanks. Adding data.frame to cpgs_interval did the trick.